# How to use putty?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, putty

I want to send a message to a device connected via serial port to Windows. I selected connection type: serial port and put Local Echo: force on. But when I type a command and click enter in the terminal window nothing happens.

How can I send a command to the device ?

Thanks

EDIT: FT232R device

Comment: What device is it you're trying to send a command to?

Comment: @ServiceManager I added the device in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more detail. Anyway, check you have the right cable. Most of the time, you need a crossover cable, I have been bitten by this before. Also, the baud rate must match the expected baud rate of the device.

Maybe tell us, what serial controller/ USB adapter and what device you use.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the baud-rate, bits and parity on the serial port.

[Setup Serial Console Connection using PuTTy](https://kb.cyberoam.com/default.asp?id=2193)

Comment: This is the motor I use http://www.velmex.com/Downloads/Instructions_Manuals/VXM_Instructions/vxm_user_manl.pdf And in the document it says "The standard RS-232 communication settings on the VXM are 9600 baud, 8 data, no parity, and 1 stop bit." This are the default setting in Putty for a serial port. In the link you send I have the same thing until step 4. When I click open the terminal opens but password does not appear.

Comment: How do  you connect to the motor? Are you using a serial to usb adapter? Are you sure that you're using the right COM? Try changing to COM2, COM3, COM4, etc.

Comment: thanks for the help. I found the problem I had to add ^,R at the end of the command.